# how to plot the graph to show the number of null values for all the columns in the dataset using only Count Plot?

Tags: python, seaborn, isnull

first I have written the code to find the number of null values in each column by using the following code:

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

after that I am not getting an idea of how to write a code for `countplot` function to get the desired output as shown in the image.

desired output:

[image: desired Output image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'Y': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 6],
    'value1': [4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, None, 5],
    'value2': [5, 4, None, 2, 1, 3, 6, 9]
})

# find dataframe nulls count
data = df.isnull().sum()

# create figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
# set Y axis label
ax.set_ylabel('count')
# set orientation for X axis labels
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
# draw bar chart
ax.bar(df.columns, data)
plt.show()
```

Seaborn solution:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'cnt': list(itertools.chain(*[[row['index']] * row['cnt'] for idx, row in df.isnull().sum().to_frame('cnt').reset_index().iterrows()]))})
sns.countplot(x = 'cnt', data = data)
plt.show()
```

Comment: hello dear, thanks for your valuable response, but the I need solution using seaborn countplot() instead of bar()..this is the main problem I am facing...

Comment: Added solution using seaborn countplot. It's a bit ugly, but seems to work.